# Wrote a script to get my followers on Twitter. The output is a list. Need to convert that to a data frame

Tags: r

Below is the code. You can get **consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret** from https://apps.twitter.com/

```
require(twitteR)

#Accessing Twitter Api

consumer_key <- "xxxxx"
consumer_secret <- "xxxx"
access_token <- "xxxxx"
access_secret <- "xxxxx" 

setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)

followers <- getUser("ni_kansal")

myfollowers <- followers$getFollowers()

for (i in 1:length(myfollowers)){

  df[i, 1] <- data.frame(myfollowers[[i]])

}
```

Output should be a data frame that has the following followers like below:

```
b_abhishek
pankajexpressia
shobhit1
Ramasted
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe `twitteR` has been deprecated in favor of [`rtweet`](https://github.com/mkearney/rtweet), but in any case, `twitteR` has a `twListToDF` function that converts from the list structure you have to a `data.frame`.

This is documented in the vignette under

## 5.3  Conversion to data.frames

Answer (score 0):

Use the following package::function `df<-rtweet::get_followers(user="potus")` resulting into the data.frame you initially wanted.

```
 >class(df)
 [1] "data.frame"
```